# WSO2 - error decoding json message in input to proxy: Cannot call method "info" of undefined

Tags: javascript, wso2

I am trying to write a proxy in wso2 which, given an input in jason format, calls a webservice with a slightly different signature. I wrote a Javascript function to perform the transformation but I get the following error message:

> [2021-10-23 14:21:14,520] ERROR {ScriptMediator} - {proxy:cambioStatoPratica} The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "info" of undefined (#3) in  at line number 3
> at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
> at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:395)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:290)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:258)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:228)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:375)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "info" of undefined (#3)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3731)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2258)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2251)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__19._c_script_0(:3)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__19.call()
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__19.call()
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__19.exec()
> at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
> ... 16 more

this is the small eg simple proxy I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="changeStatus" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_97b72a79-6507-4b7b-9d46-1d3e6e07931c">
            <address uri="[MY HTTP REST SERVICE]">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </address>
        </endpoint>
        <inSequence>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var plInput = mc.getPayloadJSON();
                 
                log.info("Log messaggio ricevuto: "+ JSON.stringify(plInput)); 
                 
                var localRespinta = true;
                var localConclusa = true;
                
                if (plInput.stato == 1)
                {
                    localRespinta = false;
                    localConclusa = false;
                    
                }
                if (plInput.stato == 2)
                {
                    localRespinta = false;
                    localConclusa = true;
                    
                }
                if (plInput.stato == 3)
                {
                    localRespinta = false;
                    localConclusa = true;
                    
                }

                var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                var keys = Object.keys(plInput);
                var response = 
                {
                            "key":      plInput.key,
                            "id":       plInput.id,
                            "motivo":   plInput.motivo,
                            "respinta": localRespinta,
                            "conclusa": localConclusa
                };
               
               log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator"+JSON.stringify(response));
               mc.setPayloadJSON(response);]]></script>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've never worked with WSO2 myself, but let's take a look at the error message you're getting.  It's this:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "info" of undefined (#3) in at line number 3

The error seems clear enough.  You're trying to call an `info` method on something that's `undefined`, and you can't call methods on `undefined`.

Let's take a look at line 3 of your script, where the error tells us the problem is:

```js
                log.info("Log messaggio ricevuto: "+ JSON.stringify(plInput));
```

There's certainly a call to a `info` method here.  Therefore `log` must be undefined.

On line 1 of your script there is a variable called `mc` which I can't see defined, but since your script got past that line, `mc` must be something that WSO2 defines for you.  However, looking through the rest of your script, I see the following line towards the bottom:

```js
                var log = mc.getServiceLog();
```

So it seems `log` isn't something WSO2 defines for you.  It's something you're defining in your script, and the problem is that you are attempting to use it before it's defined.

The fix is therefore to move the line that declares `log` above line 3, so that that part of your code looks like the following:

```js
                var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                log.info("Log messaggio ricevuto: "+ JSON.stringify(plInput));
```

Comment: incredible. I have checked the code dozens of times and  I have not noticed that I have not declared the variable. rookie mistake :(
thank you so much